How to make my Tkinter app fit the whole window no matter the size?
I made a Tkinter app using Python. I want it to auto-resize and fill the whole window no matter how I resize it.
The problem is that when I expand the window size (using my cursor), grey space appears on the borders to fill the gaps (see the image below).
Grey space filling
Here is the code minus the unnecessary details :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl


root = tk.Tk()

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

widgets_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text = "Insert Data")
widgets_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 10)

day_label = ttk.Label(widgets_frame, text = "Date")
day_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = (0, 5), sticky = "ew")
day_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
day_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = (0, 5), sticky = "ew") 

walking_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
walking_entry.insert(0, "Walking duration (min)")
walking_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: walking_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
walking_entry.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = (0, 5), sticky = "ew")

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text = "Insert")
button.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = "nsew")

treeFrame = ttk.Frame(frame)
treeFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 10)
treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(treeFrame)
treeScroll.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")

cols = ("Day", "Walking")

treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeFrame, show = "headings", yscrollcommand = treeScroll.set, columns = cols, height = 13)
treeview.column("Day", width = 100)
treeview.column("Walking", width = 50)
treeview.pack()
treeScroll.config(command = treeview.yview)

root.mainloop()

Does anybody have a suggestion that would help me solve this issue ?
Thanks.
I added this line of code because, in another thread, they said it helps with expanding the widgets equally when the window size increases :
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight = 1)

Unfortunately, even after doing so, I didn't notice any changes.

You need to apply rowconfigure and columnconfigure to all containers (frame and widget_frame)

It is not clear what the final result you want when the window is resized.  Should only the treeview widget be expanded to fill the available space?

You could use expand = True, fill = BOTH as an attribute for the required widgets to expand them to full size.

Here are the solutions I have applied to your example code.
It's interesting that the different managers work together!
There were grid sticky and pack omissions that caused the problem.
Plus the need to use rowconfigure and columnconfigure on frame instead of root.
Here is a selection of frame.columnconfigure values that will change the behaviour of widgets within.
if False:
    frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # left widget expand (Entries)
elif True:
    frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # right widget expand (Treeview)
else:
    frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1) # both widgets expanded

I've kept pack and grid managers since they all work together!
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl

root=tk.Tk()
frame=ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="y") # expanded
# Required
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1) # expand both widgets in frame

widgets_frame=ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Insert Data")
widgets_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="nsew") # expanded
# Required
widgets_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
widgets_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

day_label=ttk.Label(widgets_frame, text="Date")
day_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")
day_entry=ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
day_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew") 

walking_entry=ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
walking_entry.insert(0, "Walking duration (min)")
walking_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: walking_entry.delete("0", "end"))
walking_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

button=ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text="Insert")
button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

treeFrame=ttk.Frame(frame)
treeFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, sticky="nsew") # expanded

treeScroll=ttk.Scrollbar(treeFrame)
treeScroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

cols=("Day", "Walking")

treeview=ttk.Treeview(treeFrame, show="headings", yscrollcommand=treeScroll.set, columns=cols, height=13)

treeview.column("Day", width=100)
treeview.column("Walking", width=50)
treeview.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="y") # expanded
treeScroll.config(command=treeview.yview)

root.mainloop()

